# Symfony EntityType choice that isn't the specified entity

Tags: symfony

I have an EntityType choice, like this:

```
->add('responsible', EntityType::class, [
   'class' => User::class,
   'choice_label' => function ($u) {
      return $u->getName()." (".$u->getEmail().")";
   },
   'placeholder' => null,
   'choices' => $userChoices,
```

Now, this outputs:

```
<select ...>. 
   <option value="xxx">Amando (amando@abreu.com)</option>
   <option value="yyy">George (george@abreu.com)</option>
</select>
```

However, I wanna have another option that isn't a user, like this:

```
select ...>. 
   <option value="xxx">Amando (amando@abreu.com)</option>
   <option value="yyy">George (george@abreu.com)</option>
   <option value="null">Create new</option>
</select>
```

If someone selects this "Create new" option, some form elements will be added to add this new user. That functionality is out of the scope of this question though. This question is just about the the option that isn't an entity.

If I just do:

```
$userChoices["Create new"] = null;
```

I of course get:

```
Argument #1 ($choice) must be of type object, null given
```

Is what I'm trying to do here possible? How? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`EntityType::class & 'class' => User::class` will ensure that your options are related with User Entity. So you can't add any other options which are not related with that entity. If you really need something custom, then use `ChoiceType` instead of `EntityType`. Then you can manually prepare those options using another method & can attach it in your `choices`.

Something like this

```
->add('responsible', ChoiceType::class, [
   'placeholder' => null,
   'choices' => $this->getResponsibleOptions()
```

Then declare a private function for getResponsibleOptions like this

```
   private function getResponsibleOptions()
   {
    $responsibleOptions = $this->userRepository->findAll();

    $options = [];

    $totalOptions = count($responsibleOptions);
    for($i = 0; $i < $totalOptions; $i++){
        $options[ $responsibleOptions[$i]->getName()] = $responsibleOptions[$i]->getId();
    }

    return $options;
}
```